# How to change alert message "cannot open the specified files." in hyperlink formula

Tags: excel, hyperlink, alert

I have a cell (Sheet1!$A$1) that uses the hyperlink with vlookup function like:

```
(=HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP($R$2,'Vessel plan.xlsm'!table1,'Monthly Berthing Plan template'!$Y$11,0),"FILE"))
```

to link to another cell to open a corresponding excel file.

Some situations, the file attach not yet ready so an alert message "Cannot open the specified files" appears.

I want to change the content of alert message to "The file is not ready".

What should I do now?

Comment: wrap in an if() statement - if the result is text then display message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.